# Can I create a Symfony form submission, entirely in the controller?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, symfony

I have a Symfony FormType including some onPostSubmit actions in an Event Listener. The form is for uploading an image.

I want to have additional functionality where instead of upload an image from the browser, users can pick from the Dropbox photos using [Dropbox Drop-ins Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js)

The flow is, click to launch the "Chooser", pick photos, upload the response from Dropbox via ajax to my controller. My Symfony controller receives a request containing an array of these:

```
"bytes" : "7466873",
"icon" : "https://www.dropbox.com/static/images/icons64/page_white_picture.png",
"link" : "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/some-image/IMG_8956.JPG",
"name" : "IMG_8956.JPG",
"thumbnailLink" : "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/some-image”
```

What I want to do in my controller, is turn that into a normal `$form->handleRequest($request);` so I can use the same form, same validation, same onPostSubmit actions.

Is it possible to "fake" a submitted form completely in a controller?

```
public function dbUploadAction(Request $request)
{

    // check it's an ajax request
    if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException();
    }

    $files  = $request->get('files');

    // create an instance of the form to submit I want to submit to
    $document = new Document();
    $form = $this->createForm('document', $document);

    // do something with $files here

    $form->submit( my $files );

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // perform some action...
    // continue as if form was submitted by user from browser
    }

    $r = $this->container->get('serializer')->serialize($files, 'json');
    return new Response($r);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have done something similar when running some unit tests. I was sending some JSON to the controller via a Test Controller and treating it like a form submission:

```
// convert the JSON into an array
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

// instantiate the new Document
$document= new Document();
// create the empty Document form
$form = $this->createForm(new DocumentType(), $document);

// bind the array (of Document fields) to the form, to populate it
$form->bind($data);
// now validate the form
if($form->isValid()){
    // business as usual
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the end I think it's better for me to create services out of the functionality and upload the images using code shared by my listeners and my controllers.

Comment: Good luck with your project.